# Rounded border in Xamarin.Forms.Entry keeps getting cut

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My rounded border entry is getting cut out. The code in my custom renderer makes the rounded corners have larger widths than my set border width. How do I remove the increased border width on the corners?

[image: Screenshot of entry]
Code:

```
var y = (float)CalculateResolutionScaling(25);
var x = new float[] { y, y, y, y, y, y, y, y };
var z = new RectF(35, 35, 35, 35);
var shape = new ShapeDrawable(new global::Android.Graphics.Drawables.Shapes.RoundRectShape(x, null, null));
shape.Paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
shape.Paint.StrokeWidth = (float)CalculateResolutionScaling(control.BorderWidth * 2.75);
Control.Background = shape;
shape.Paint.Color = control.BorderColor.ToAndroid();
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add this to your styles:

**RoundedCorner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<corners android:radius="10dp" />
<padding
    android:bottom="3dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="3dp" />
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="@color/White"
    android:startColor="@color/White" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/Gray" />
</shape>
```

Then use it something like this:

```
 Control.Background = ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(this.Resources, Resource.Style.RoundedCorner, null);
```

In case you want to change the colour of the Corner just change the stroke colour in the XML above.

If you have any queries feel free to revert.

Comment: The properties of the entry need to be customizable. How would I create the XML in code?

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve rounded corner entry in xamarin.forms without a custom render. you can use a Frame to create rounded corner effect.